# Is there a typeclass for references similar to the MArray class for mutable arrays?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, mutable

The MArray class provides generic functions for working with mutable arrays of various sorts in both ST and IO contexts. I haven't been able to find a similar class for working with both STRefs and IORefs. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 6):

The [`ref-fd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ref-fd) package provides it:

```
class Monad m => MonadRef r m | m -> r where
    [...]
```

or with type families, [`ref-tf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ref-tf):

```
class Monad m => MonadRef m where
    type Ref m :: * -> *
    [...]
```

Another answer suggested the [monad-statevar](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-statevar-0.1) package which doesn't have the functional dependency. It also has separate `HasGet` and `HasPut` members and no abstraction over the `newRef` functionality.

Aside from the different methods in each, the functional dependency is a design trade-off. Consider the following two simplified classes:

```
class MRef1 r m where
   newRef1 :: a -> m (r a)
   readRef1 :: r a -> m a

class MRef2 r m | m -> r where
   newRef2 :: a -> m (r a)
   readRef2 :: r a -> m a
```

With `MRef1`, both the monad type and the reference type can vary freely, so the following code has a type error:

```
useMRef1 :: ST s Int
useMRef1 = do
   r <- newRef1 5
   readRef1 r

No instance for (MRef1 r0 (ST s)) arising from a use of `newRef1'
The type variable `r0' is ambiguous
```

We have to add an extra type signature somewhere to say that we want to use `STRef`.

In contrast, the same code works fine for `MRef2` without any extra signature. The signature on the definition saying that the whole code has type `ST s Int`, combined with the functional dependency `m -> r` means that there is only one `r` type for a given `m` type and so the compiler knows that our existing instance is the only possible one and we must want to use `STRef`.

On the flip side, suppose we want to make a new kind of reference, e.g. `STRefHistory` that tracks all the values that have ever been stored in it:

```
newtype STRefHistory s a = STRefHistory (STRef s [a])
```

The `MRef1` instance is fine because we are allowed multiple reference types for the same monad type:

```
instance MRef1 (STRefHistory s) (ST s) where
   newRef1 a = STRefHistory <$> newSTRef [a]
   readRef1 (STRefHistory r) = head <$> readSTRef r
```

but the equivalent `MRef2` instance fails with:

```
Functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations:
  instance MRef2 (STRef s) (ST s) -- Defined at mref.hs:28:10
  instance MRef2 (STRefHistory s) (ST s) -- Defined at mref.hs:43:10
```

I also mentioned the type family version, which is quite similar in expressive power to the functional dependency; the reference type is a "type function" of the monad type so there can again only be one per monad. The syntax ends up being a bit different and in particular you can just say `MonadRef m` in constraints, without stating what the reference type is within the constraint.

It's also plausible to have the reversed functional dependency:

```
class MRef2 r m | r -> m where
```

so that each reference type can live in just one monad, but you can still have several reference types for a monad. Then you'd need type signatures on your references but not on your monadic computations as a whole.

Comment: I thought that those "refs" are different because thay have different meaning. I.e. `IORef` cannot be optimized away in contrast to `STRef`. And `TVar` is kinda element of optimistic parallel computations.

Comment: How does ref-fd compare to monad-statevar?

Comment: Both `IORef` and `STRef` have the same underlying implementation, as far as I know. It's just that you can "escape" the `ST` monad with `runST`.

Comment: `monad-statevar` doesn't have the functional dependency from the Monad type to the reference type, which means that it admits more instances (e.g. you might find some other reference type to use with IO) but type inference will generally work out better with `ref-fd`.

Comment: Can you give an example of that?

Comment: Yes, Ganesh Sittampalam, of type inference working out better.

Comment: I edited the post to add some discussion of the options.

Answer (score 5):

[Control.Monad.StateVar](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-statevar-0.1/docs/Control-Monad-StateVar.html) has a typeclass which lets you `get` and `put` IORefs and STRefs identically.

Comment: How does monad-statevar compare to ref-fd?